# pm2 deployment to aws micro instance of ubuntu 12.0

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have ran a pm2 deploy script that seems to have hung, I am running a aws EC2 Micro instance runnning ubuntu 12. The only indication I have of what's wrong that I can tell is a message I got when trying to ssh in
`System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0`

Here is my config for pm2, what I am wondering is what are the best next steps to resolve this, should I stop and start my instance then rerun my pm2 deploy script? I was able to ssh in but I can't run any commands. (well I can run some commands, but it is super super slow, `ls` takes like 3 minutes)

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: "Website",
        script: "npm",
        args: "start",
        watch: false,
        env: {
          NODE_ENV: "development",
          URL: "http://dev.website.com",
        },
      },
    ],
  
    deploy: {
      development: {
        key: "~/.ssh/website.pem",
        user: "ubuntu",
        host: "ec2-random.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        ref: "origin/development",
        repo: "git@github.com:website/website.git",
        path: "/home/ubuntu/website",
        "pre-deploy-local": "",
        "post-deploy":
          "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env development && npm install -g gatsby-cli",
        "pre-setup": "",
      },
    },
  }
```

Update: I finally got some returns in my terminal from the ubuntu ssh instance, one thing to note was the pm2 deploy was still running and I just hit ctrl+c and it said succesfull deployment, so not sure if it was continuing to do something over and over. Here is the output from running the following commands (pm2 logs, and ls)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-48-164:~$ Failed to import the site module
ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 570, in <module>
studioConscious
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 557, in main
ubuntu@ip-172-31-48-164:~$     known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 345, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 213, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/operator.py", line 22, in <module>
    from builtins import abs as _abs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _handle_fromlist
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: `Ubuntu 12` does not sound like a version number you would be using with Python 3.6 (or using at all, these days). use `lsb_release -a` to get the proper distribution info.

Comment: I think I meant 18, I was a little tired. I will check tho

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rebooting and running my deploy script again it is working now. If anyone could shed some light on why it hung I will select that as the answer.

Thanks